# Do I have to re-check luggage on a layover in Philadelphia?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, luggage, airport-transfer

I booked a flight from Ottawa (Canada) to Venice (Italy) but it has a transfer in Philadelphia, will I have to re-check my luggage in Philadelphia? The trip was booked through flighthub and though it appears to all be operated through American Airlines, the actual plane companies are different ones.

Comment: Is the entire trip on a single ticket? In other words, if you look up the confirmation code on American's site, does it show the entire trip or just one of the segments?

Answer (score 6):

As Ottawa is on the list of [pre-clearance airports](http://www.cbp.gov/border-security/ports-entry/operations/preclearance) you would have already passed American customs and immigration in Canada.

Judging from [Flightaware](http://flightaware.com/live/findflight?origin=CYOW&destination=LIPZ) you're flying with [Air Wisconsin](http://www.airwis.com/) to Philadelphia, which has a partnership with American Airlines so that should mean...**no need to recheck your bags** ! :)